# LINQ Select new returns ObjectMaterializer

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that looks like this:

```
        var matches = (from das in dc.GetTable<datos_amef_secuencia>()
                          where das.ID_SUBETAPA == IDSubStage
                          group das by das.AMEF_MODO_FALLA into gamf
                             select new{ MODODEFALLA = gamf.Select(das => das.AMEF_MODO_FALLA),
                                         CONTEOMODODEFALLA = gamf.Count()}).ToList();
```

The query itself has the information that i need, the problem radicates whenever i try to use the information in the variable "matches" , for example, if i use a messagebox to print "MODODEFALLA" :

```
        foreach( var element in matches)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(element.MODODEFALLA.ToString());
        }
```

It returns something like this:

```
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Implementation.ObjectMaterializer<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader>.Convert<string>
```

I've tried several methods to print the results of the query but the one that works is the method .Single , but it only returns 1 item of the list, in certain situations i have more than one item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MODODEFALLA` appears to be a *collection* of items - you *shouldn't* care what the underlying type is so long as you can iterate through it or call other Linq methods on it.

One option is to iterate through the collection instead of trying to call `ToString` on the collection:

```
    foreach( var element in matches)
    {
        foreach(var item in element.MODODEFALLA)
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
    }
```

or project the collection to a single string using `string.Join`:

```
    foreach( var element in matches)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string,Join("; ", element.MODODEFALLA));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! You manage to approach the problem very easily, it works flawless.  I'm pretty new to LINQ.